# How do I create an access table showing possession of computer programs by computer?

Tags: database

I am new to access and trying to create a database for my company. One of the tables I would like to create is a table that shows the demand of computer programs for each computer. I have an excel sheet where the rows are the computers and the columns are the programs. If a computer possesses the program there is either a "x" (for simple programs), or the current version of the program (e.g. 2.0.0.0). I can duplicate this table in access but I feel like I'm going at it the wrong way. Is there a better way to show the computer possessing multiple programs? I need to be able to create reports on the versions of software. What is the best way to tabulate this kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

You actually need four tables:

- `computer`: include details for each computer on its own (no programs), including primary key `computer_id`
- `program`: include details for each program on its own (no computers), including primary key `program_id`, but don't include the version number here
- `program_version`: this table has three columns: primary key `version_id`, foreign key `program_id` from table `program`, and version number
- `computer_program`: this table has two columns: foreign key `computer_id` from `computer`, and foreign key `version_id` from table `program_version`

To pull the data you'd need for your report, your query would probably look something like:

```
SELECT computer.make, program.vendor, program_version.version_num /* add other columns as needed */
    FROM computer_program cp
    INNER JOIN computer c ON cp.computer_id = c.computer_id
    INNER JOIN program_version pv ON cp.version_id = pv.version_id
    INNER JOIN program p ON pv.program_id = p.program_id
    WHERE c.make = 'Dell' OR pv.version_num = 4 OR p.vendor = 'Microsoft'
```

Comment: So for the last table I need to create a record for each program associated with each computer? comp1-pro1, comp1-pro2, comp2-pro1 etc.? Then my bigger question is how to create a fillable form showing all the possible programs for each computer. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Yep, that's how you'd structure `computer_program`. I added a sample query to get you started. As for filling out forms (I'm guessing as a webpage), that's outside the scope of this question, but there are plenty of resources online for that (including StackOverflow!). If you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: If your form is an MS Access form, your master form would be the computer and your subform would be all the software on that computer. Are you intending to manually type in all the existing info? A better idea would be to load it into your MS Access database from the Excelfile (data migration)

Comment: @ElectricLlama .. I have already added all my current data to my tables and created a form w/ subform which shows each computer and a list of the programs it possesses and I see how a user can add programs through this form. However, what I'm looking for is a form that shows all the possible programs with check boxes or version lists next to them. Am I headed in the right direction with this form/subform?

Comment: I have already added all my current data to my tables and created a form w/ subform which shows each computer and a list of the programs it possesses and I see how a user can add programs through this form. However, what I'm looking for is a form that shows all the possible programs with check boxes or version lists next to them. Am I headed in the right direction with this form/subform?